# curl command works on terminal but not on shell script

Tags: bash, curl

I'm writing a bash script to make a request on a server to send information via API and change the status about that information.

From terminal this works for me:

```
curl -s -w "GET" https://mysite/page.php?id=43982934&send=Yhd6yryr87237846dh&status=1";
```

If I go from browser on the same URL, it works. But when I run this from inside my script with this command, nothing works.

```
cmd='curl -s -w "GET" https://mysite/page.php?id=43982934&send=Yhd6yryr87237846dh&status=1"';
```

Tried to run it directly like terminal, but couldn't get it to work.

## EDIT

Script is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd='curl -s -w "GET" "https://mysite/page.php?id=43982934&send=Yhd6yryr87237846dh&status=1"'
    if [ "$var" != "$extension" ]; then
            ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/temp/name.extension -c copy /var/www/html/temp/namefile.extension
    fi;
cmd='curl -s -w "GET" "https://mysite/page.php?id=43982934&send=Yhd6yryr87237846dh&status=2"'
```

I need to set a status for each ffmpeg process!

Comment: can you show your script ?

Comment: Nothing works? What is the output from CURL?

Comment: This is another classic case of [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Don't ever use variables to store commands, they are meant for holding data. Use a function or an array. 

The issue you are facing is the result of Word splitting of the individual arguments when you define it in a variable `cmd`, the `actual` curl command did not get to see the entire list of arguments.

Comment: Use an array,

`cmdArgs=()
cmdArgs=( "curl" "-s" "-w" "GET" "https://mysite/page.php?id=43982934&send=Yhd6yryr87237846dh&status=1" )`

and do a proper quoted array expansion as below which will preserve your individual words and run the command without any splitting done.

`"${cmdArgs[@]}"`

or use a function


`curlCmd() {
    curl -s -w "GET" "https://mysite/page.php?id=43982934&send=Yhd6yryr87237846dh&status=1"
}`

and call it as `curlCmd`

Comment: thank! solved with  `cmdArgs=( "curl" "-s" "-w" "GET" "https://mysite/page.php?id=43982934&send=Yhd6yryr87237846dh&status=1`